# Creating my own bind() function using apply() in Javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

As an exercise, I am trying to create my own bind() function using apply() and prototypal inheritance that I have just learned.

This is my code:

```js
// Create your own bind() using call() and apply()
const lizard = {
    phrase: 'slither',
    say(phraseToSay) {
        if (!phraseToSay) phraseToSay = this.phrase
        console.log('sss' + phraseToSay)
    },
}

const dragon = {
    phrase: 'sizzle',
}

// My Answer
Function.prototype.mybind = function (object) {
    return () => this.apply(object, arguments)
}

// Solution
Function.prototype.solbind = function (object) {
    let self = this
    return function () {
        self.apply(object, arguments)
    }
}

dragon.say = lizard.say.mybind(dragon)

lizard.say()
dragon.say()
lizard.say('sexy')
dragon.say('sexy')
```

This is the Output:

```
ssslither
sss[object Object]
ssssexy
sss[object Object]
```

The solution is to use `self=this`. But it looks ugly in my eyes...
I am trying to do it with just this and arrow functions. But for some reason, `apply()` is passing the first argument which is the object itself as an actual argument of the target function. I do not understand why this is and how I can achieve the result I want without saving `this` into another variable.

Comment: Arrow functions do not have an implicit `arguments` parameter. Within an arrow function, `arguments` refers to `arguments` in the enclosing scope, if that exists

Comment: `return (...args) => this.apply(object, args)`. Both the keywords `arguments` and `this` within an arrow function are bound to the parent function.

Comment: why not use `class`? Seems `lizard ` extends from `dragon`.

Comment: Actually that solution is wrong as well, since it doesn't consider extra arguments to `bind` that should be partially applied. Better: `function(receiver, ...boundArgs) { return (...callArgs) => this.call(receiver, ...boundArgs, ...callArgs); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do:

```
.... = function (object) { 
  return () => this.apply(object, arguments)
}
```

You're referring to the `arguments` object bounded to the outer function expression, not your arrow function, as arrow functions don't have their own arguments binding. In this case, that arguments object will contain `dragon`, as you're using:

```
dragon.say = lizard.say.mybind(dragon)
```

So, your arguments object will contain `dragon` which will be passed as an argument to your `say` method when using `.apply(object, arguments)`.

In the case of the provided solution, they're returning a function expression, which, unlike an arrow function, does have its own `arguments` binding, so in that case, the `arguments` object refers to the arguments passed into the function returned by `solbind()`.

You can fix your code by using ES6 [rest parameter syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) `(...)` instead of referring to the arguments object. This way `args` will refer to the arguments passed into the "bound" function:

```js
// Create your own bind() using call() and apply()
const lizard = {
    phrase: 'slither',
    say(phraseToSay) {
        if (!phraseToSay) phraseToSay = this.phrase
        console.log('sss' + phraseToSay)
    },
}

const dragon = {
    phrase: 'sizzle',
}

// My Answer
Function.prototype.mybind = function (object) {
    return (...args) => this.apply(object, args)
}

// Solution
Function.prototype.solbind = function (object) {
    let self = this
    return function () {
        self.apply(object, arguments)
    }
}

dragon.say = lizard.say.mybind(dragon)

lizard.say()
dragon.say()
lizard.say('sexy')
dragon.say('sexy')
```